# Ruby on rails loop- using API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I'm working on an app which works around API from one of the cinemas. So I'm using XML file from them which is updated every day (just a list of movies with simple details). I'm getting the data using Nokogiri (I'll probably need Cron so it will parse every day automatically) this way:

```
require 'open-uri'

@doc=Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.kinoballada.info/repertuar/export/small/dzien/xml"))
@doc.css('dzien').each do |node|
    children=node.children
Movie.create(
    :name => children.css('tytul').inner_text
)
```

dzien=day

tytul=title

Every day it should check the database.
If title is in database and in XML it does nothing. 
If title is in database and not in XML it should delete this title from database.
If title is not in database and in XML it works creates new title in database.

In simple words- the database contains the same titles as XML file.

The problem is- I got no experience with Ruby or Rails and do not know how to use a loop and I need it for tomorrow so no time to catch up. Can anyone help me with the loop?

Comment: Why are you not using rake task which will be started by cron. You can use gem 'whenever' what this.

Comment: Yeah I'll try to use it but i need to compare movies anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way...

```
    require 'open-uri'

  @doc=Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.kinoballada.info/repertuar/export/small/dzien/xml"))
    movie_array = []
    @doc.css('dzien').each do |node|
    children=node.children
    movie_array << children.css('tytul').inner_text
    Movie.find_or_create_by(
    :name => children.css('tytul').inner_text
    )
    end
    movies_to_delete = Movie.where.not(name: movie_array)
    movies_to_delete.destroy_all
```

Answer (score 0):

Also- am I thinking right that my schedule.rb file when using Cron should look like that?

```
every 1.day, at '0:00' do
runner "db:seeds"
```

Simple as that?